# Keyboard Map is Changed Randomly

Tags: gnome, keyboard, keyboard-layout

I'm using xmodmap to bind a key to the numbersign `#` like so: `xmodmap -e "keycode 49 = numbersign asciitilde"`.

This works fine but the changes are regularly reverted by some background process, possibly `gnome-settings-daemon`.

Is there a way to permanently change this key or to stop gnome-settings-daemon from overriding my keyboard settings?

Comment: This is happening to me too after upgrade from 13.04 to 14.04. It changes the keymap randomly, but appears to be more common after logging in and when coming out of suspend mode.

I killed gnome-settings-demon and that seems to keep it from happening so far, but that is not a workable solution.

Comment: This problem occurs for me on 20.04 as well, probably since the .3 update. I've asked where I can report this here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1362049/where-can-i-report-keyboard-map-is-changed-randomly The issue occurs as noted above, but also when connecting/disconnecting devices. Presumably the daemon runs whenever that happens, leading to the erroneous behaviour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To prevent gnome settings daemon from overriding other settings use `dconf-editor`, select `/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/keyboard/` and uncheck the active checkbox.